# How does the TFS 2012 burndown work for tasks created and worked on in the same day?

Tags: scrum, resource-planning, tfs, burn-charts

It appears that the TFS 2012 burndown works a bit differently than I expect.

Suppose my current iteration is at 100 hours remaining out of 200 total original estimate, and my three team members each create a task today, estimate each at 6 hours, and complete these tasks.  Thus, we discovered and completed 18 hours of work that we didn't realize were there.  I would expect the entire burndown to "shift up", have it recalculate based on 218 hours total, and we would now be at 100.  Thus we would show a good burn for today: we burned down 18 hours, going from 118 to 100, remaining.  The goal burndown line would get a bit steeper, and we would reevaluate if it is realistic given the newly discovered work.

However, it seems that TFS's burndown chart ignores the "original estimate" in some (all?) cases and would show no progress today; those 18 hours are not reflected anywhere in the burndown.

This doesn't quite make sense to me--the upshot is, if I create a task **today** and finish it **today**, no hours are burned; but, if I create a task **today**, work on it today, and finish it **tomorrow**, then some but not all of its hours burn. Really?

How best to deal with this situation? Do we need to change the way we think of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing is how TFS currently works. I've logged this with the Product Team a couple of times, and I've heard a couple of ways it might be solved in the future, but for now your tasks found and solved on the same day are not reflected.

The funny thing is that the burndown will still be correct. Any hours found and resolved on the same day have a net result of 0 hours, so the burndown should remain in place. So you can trust the prediction (which is the most important piece of the burndown), but you cannot see exactly how much work was done each day (which scrum cares a lot less about).

There are a number of [UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5075722-fix-the-burndown-trendline-algorithm) tickets on this and a there might be bugs files on [connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

### So, how to deal...

- If you want the graph to be accurate, [use the Report Server version of the burndown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731588.aspx), I believe that that graph is correct.
- Get the data from the warehouse using [Excel Powerpivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd695785.aspx) and then you're completely in control over the algorithm used. (steal the Excel file from a MSF for Agile project's SharePoint portal)
- Or draw your own burndown.
- Do nothing and believe the trend.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.  I agree the last day of the burndown will be correct, but the burndown on individual days is wrong, as it will show no work completed for such created and worked-on tasks.

Comment: Do you have any info on how to use the report server version of the burndown?

Comment: I would not put much value in the accuracy of the burndown. As a team we know what happened, others can ask us but the burndown should not be used for status reporting anyways, it's mostly a planning tool!

Comment: Added links to Report server and Excel versions of the report. This requires that your TFS server is configured with Reporting enabled and/or Sharepoint integration.

Comment: Unfortunately, looks like my team project doesn't have that enabled.  Anyway, if the burndown is too inaccurate, there is no point to having it.  If the instant-in-time comparison based on remaining work vs. capacity is the only relevant data, there's no need for a chart at all.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Just remember, remaining capacity vs planned != burndown.

Comment: The burndown is remaining work vs goal, with the goal line starting at the total work.  TFS seems to calculate the goal line based on the maximum of the nightly snapshots of remaining work, whereas I want it to calculate it based on the original estimate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of the burndown chart. The burndown is there to show you how much work is **remaining** in a sprint at any point in time, not to record how much work you've done.

If you had 100 hours to do and you add 18 hours worth of tasks and burn down those 18 then the net effect on the work remaining is zero, hence the burndown chart will show zero progress.

I know it seems harsh to see no credit for the work but the fact is if you had 100 hours to do at the start of the day and those 100 hours still remain at the end then its right that the burndown reflects that.

Comment: I disagree.  If all I care about is remaining vs. capacity, why have a burndown at all--you just need two numbers to compare?  The burndown shows recent history and trends.  Suppose we have tasks that total 100 hours estimated at the start, and then discover 200 more hours of tasks later. Those 200 hours of work were always there; they just weren't discovered until later.  I want my overall burndown to start at 300 hours, not 100--otherwise, the daily progress shown in the burndown is meaningless.  Unplanned tasks are just as important as planned tasks.

Comment: Also, TFS does show these tasks in the burndown, it just fails to capture hours burned the same day the task is created.

Answer (score 1):

Patrick, let me tell you very briefly how Jira manages this. Why? Because I believe it is the right way to handle it :)

In Jira you start the sprint explicitly. Once it is started, all changes to the sprint in regards to content leads to a changed sprint scope, either increased or decreased.

In your case - starting off with 200 hours and then adding 18 hours will never give you an "updated" start point of the burn down (e.g. 200 hours + 18 hours) because these are considered as a change to sprint scope.

What you will see is that the burn down get a spike equal to 18 hours on that day and, if burned down the same day, you will also burn down those same hours (see below around feb 12).

[image]

In theory (and our practice), if you start off with 100 hours because that is your capacity, and you suddenly find 50 more, you cannot just add them into the sprint. Because you do not have the capacity (unless you initiate lots of OT). If those newly found 50 hours must be done in the sprint you should remove another set of 50 hours because those hours are not what your team initially committed to (they commit to 100 hours, not 150).

I would say that the TFS burndown is wrong. But because it doesn't show the spike as Jira does, not because it doesn't increase/update the additional work added during the sprint.

Comment: I agree that having the spike is better than nothing, but I would say the overall idea is naive.  You are going to have dozens if not hundreds of hours of work discovered throughout the sprint.  The waterfall attitude is that we plan everything ahead of time, but the agile attitude says that we react to changing circumstances (i.e. discovered work) by changing along with it.

Comment: "if you start off with 100 hours because that is your capacity, and you suddenly find 50 more, you cannot just add them into the sprint."  Sure you can.  The most common scenario is that I have 150 hours capacity, and 100 hours of tasks, and later in the sprint, 0-50 or more hours of new tasks get added.  I've never had software work where all the tasks are predictable--there are always additional tasks that weren't understood before the work began.

Comment: Maybe we are talking about different things Patrick. I assume that when you use the burndown you work agile. And with agile the team commit to the work they believe they will be able to complete within the next sprint. That means that you plan "just enough" to believe that you can commit to the contents of the next sprint. Yes - some tasks will take more time, some less. But the entire concept with the burndown is to show the burndown of the committed content. If you have 150 hours capacity and you only plan to use 100 hours, you undercommit. That might be your process, but it is not agile.

Comment: Example: check out the green line and comment here: http://www.practiceagile.com/2010/02/sprint-burndown-says-lot-about-your.html. You adapt to change yes, but you adapt by adding the new things to the sprint and removing something else with the same size.

Comment: We commit to stories, not to hours.  We can only guess as to the hours; but, our historical capacity in story points can be very accurate. I think you are nuts to demand that the product owner later remove things from the sprint to allow the team to "fully commit" at the beginning, when inevitably tasks are discovered later in the sprint.  You are basically assuming the team will never discover work later in the sprint.  Instead, I prefer the team to commit to the amount of work they think they can accomplish at the story level and allow the hours to be "undercommitted".

Comment: In other words, in Scrum, TASKS are for the team, but the STORIES are what they commit to.  I want the team to commit to the STORIES, but if they have trouble coming up with all the TASKS before the end of the sprint planning, that's okay.  Since the burndown is based on TASKS, it needs to accommodate a significant addition of tasks later in the sprint.  This would make a good blog post, as I think there is confusion on this point.

Comment: Also, just FYI, "And with agile the team commit to the work they believe they will be able to complete within the next sprint."  [Agile](http://www.agilemanifesto.org/) specifies no such thing, as Agile is just a set of values and principles that says nothing about commitment schedules or sprints.  Sounds like you are thinking about Scrum.

Comment: Your quite right on your last comment - it's Scrummish, not agile as such. Let me quickly tell you how we do it in our house. Before sprint planning, Product Owner prioritize the contents of the next sprint based on recent velocity. Say 650 points. In the sprint planning meeting, the team break down all stories and estimate the sub-tasks in hours. Max 8 hours - if more, create new sub-tasks. Estimates < 8 hours are relatively exact. During sprint planning they also consider the original story point estimate of the parent issue.

Comment: Once sprint planning is complete, and assuming that the estimate in story points is still close to the velocity, the sprint start.

Comment: Now, during the sprint, things can show up. Examples are bugs identified by the end-users in production that we have to fix in the current sprint. Or an important change to a existing function to make it just a little bit more usable. These are estimated in story points and added to the current sprint. This gives the spike in the burndown. Now - if the Product Owner accept that some work is more important than other work, she also realize that something else must be less important. This results in the Product Owner removing the same amount of story points from the sprint as she just put in.

Comment: This keeps the initial number of story points as when the sprint started. Yes - sometimes the estimates are off, both ways. If some issues doesn't comply with the DOD, the story is moved to the next sprint when the sprint closes. They then attack it in the next sprint. And so the work continues. So - we commit to stories - they are estimated - we plan to use the "entire" sprint, we do not make room initially for the items that are identified during the sprint. At least it is not very Scrum'ish :)